# Will using private API 'value(forKey: "view") as? UIView' get App Store Rejection

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, iphone-privateapi

I need to get the frame of the imageView inside the tabBar and also the frame of the navigationBarButtonItem using:

```
let fifthTab = tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[4].value(forKey: "view") as? UIView { ... }

let barButtonItemView = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView { ... }
```

In both situations I'm successfully setting some other UIViews based on their frame. I read that they are private APIs and using private APIs will result in an AppStore rejection but i found plenty of examples using them between SO and GitHub. No one has confirmed wether these will or won't result in a rejection when going live to the AppStore.

Can someone confirm that using these APIs will result in a rejection or not?

Comment: why down vote a legit question? I don't understand how this is a bad question. Smh

Comment: You aren't using private API, so you don't need to worry about rejection.  You are relying on an implementation detail that isn't guaranteed not to change.

Comment: Oh, ok. I read multiple posts that said these were private APIs as opposed to them not changing. I didn’t know what to think. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on Apple. But basically will not be rejected. Apple has a special private API scanner to detect whether you use sensitive APIs. While valueForKey and view are fairly common and legal APIs, it is difficult for scanners to scan them out.